# Declaring an instance variable in another class using PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, class, scope, instance-variables, declare

I simply want to declare an instance variable in a second class in the same file.
The following example code seems okay to me, but the server results an error at the commented line:

For example:

```
<?php

class Locator {
    private $location = __FILE__;

    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->location;
    }
}

class Doc {
    private $loc = new Locator(); // [SYNTAX-ERROR] unexpected T_NEW

    public function locator() {
        return $this->loc;
    }
}

$doc = new Doc();
var_dump( $doc->locator() );

?>
```

Many thanks to everyone's help!

Comment: Class properties cannot be defined containing any value that requires run time evaluation - set the value in the constructor for the class - see the first paragraph of the [docs page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can new locator class in Doc::locator();

```
class Locator {
    private $location = __FILE__;

    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->location;
    }
}

class Doc {
    public function locator() {
        return new Locator();  // new locator here
    }
}

$doc = new Doc();
var_dump( $doc->locator() );

?>
```

Comment: Thanks to you, too! I used the __construct() function for initialization, because I need to keep the instance I declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set property because it belong to object not a class. You can fix it by creating your locator in constructor

```
class Doc {
    private $loc;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->loc = new Locator()
    }
    public function locator() {
        return $this->loc;
    }
}
```